# Jackson - unwrapping object

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, jackson

I am getting responses from server that are wrapped with some additional info. For example:

```
{
    "response_a" : ...,
    "some_metadata" : 1234,
    "more_metadata" : abcd
}

        or

{
    "response_b" : [...],
    "some_metadata" : 1234,
    "more_metadata" : abcd
}
```

The "response_x" can be custom object, list or hashmap, it can have different name depending on request.

**Is there a way deserialize just the response_x**, or get it as string using jackson?

Comment: Do you have this "response_x" property name during the deserialization process?

Comment: yes, I do. I figured out I could simply use `JSONObject.get("response_x").toString()` but I would very much like to do that using jackson...

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize above JSON to `Map` and retrieve the property using `get` method:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MapType mapType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(HashMap.class, String.class, Object.class);
Map<String, Object> result = mapper.readValue(json, mapType);
Object responseX = result.get("response_x");
```